# C# Func delegate in combination with lambda expression not correct

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, func

I have a class Employee, with some basic params, and a class employees that has a list of employee objects. I want to use the func delegate in the class employees to be able to use the following lambda expression in the main class. I think I have some syntax mistakes here... I'am getting the following error message: "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Employee' because it is not a delegate type".

Someone knows what I'am doing wrong?

Many thanks guys !!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employees lijst = new Employees();
            lijst.Add(new Employee("B1", 200));
            lijst.Add(new Employee("B2", 100));
            lijst.Add(new Employee("B3", 300));

            lijst.Wijzig((Employee b) => b.Salary += 100);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }


class Employee
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }



        public Employee(String Name, int Salary)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Salary = Salary;

        }
    }


class Employees
    {
        public Func<Employee, int> Wijzig = new Func<Employee, int>(Change);
        private ArrayList _lijst = new ArrayList();

        public void Add(Employee e)
        {
            _lijst.Add(e);
        }

        static int Change(Employee b)
        {

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes indeed, but if I change Wijzig into Change, the problem is still the same...

Comment: What is your `Wizjig` supposed to do, anyway?  What's its purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution that has no change in the Main function:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employees lijst = new Employees();
        lijst.Add(new Employee("B1", 200));
        lijst.Add(new Employee("B2", 100));
        lijst.Add(new Employee("B3", 300));

        lijst.Wijzig((Employee b) => b.Salary += 100);

        lijst.Print();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    class Employee
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }

        public Employee(String Name, int Salary)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Salary = Salary;
        }
    }


    class Employees
    {
        // [Delete]
        // public Func<Employee, int> Wijzig = new Func<Employee, int>(Change);
        private ArrayList _lijst = new ArrayList();

        public void Add(Employee e)
        {
            _lijst.Add(e);
        }

        // [Delete]
        //static int Change(Employee b)
        //{
        //    return 0;
        //}

        // [New]
        public void Wijzig(Func<Employee, int> func) 
        {
            foreach (Employee e in _lijst)
            {
                func(e);
            }
        }

        public void Print() 
        {
            foreach (Employee e in _lijst)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Name + "\t" + e.Salary);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Wijzig` is a delegate of type `Func<Employee, int>`. I.e. it's a method which accepts employee object and returns an integer. So `lijst.Wijzig` returns this delegate. If you want to invoke this delegate, you should pass employee object (according to signature `Func<Employee, int>`), but you are passing lambda delegate instead of an employee. Correct invocation:

```
  lijst.Wijzig(someEmployee);  // calls Employees.Change
```

That will invoke a `int Change(Employee b)` method. But seems like you don't want to invokde `Change` method (which does nothing, except returning zero). You want to invoke some real change - increment of salary. So, the first step you should do is change the delegate wich is assigned to `Wijzig`, and then invoke this delegate with your employee object:

```
 lijst.Wijzig = (Employee b) => { b.Salary += 100; return 0; }
 lijst.Wijzig(someEmployee); // calls lambda which we assigned
```

Notes:

- there is no sense to use `ArrayList` in .NET 2.0+ you should use generic collection like `List<Employee>` instead.
- it's not clear why your `Change` method returns an integer. Consider making it void.
- you are re-implementing functionality LINQ - there is a `ForEach` extension method which accepts an action to be performed on each item of the collection.

  ```
      var list = new List<Employee> {
          new Employee("B1", 200),
          new Employee("B2", 100),
          new Employee("B3", 300)
      };

      list.ForEach(e => e.Salary += 100);
  ```

That's it. All your code without custom classes.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply !! Is there any way to not change this line of code :"lijst.Wijzig((Employee b) => b.Salary += 100);" but to change the "Change()" method instead?

Comment: @MathiasVerhoeven `Change` method cannot be changed - it is defined during compilation and stays there. But you can do the opposite - use `Wijzig` inside `Change` method. I'll give you an example.

Comment: @MathiasVerhoeven can you describe purpose of the `Change` method as you see it?

Answer (score 0):

Your below code line to invoke `func`

```
lijst.Wijzig((Employee b) => b.Salary += 100);
```

should just be below, passing an `Employee` object

```
int result = lijst.Wijzig(lijst[0]);
```